# SQL: how to fill all empty code fields

Tags: sql, while-loop, db2

i'm working with db2
so i have some table and the question is how to fill all empty code fields

raws in the table represent some real world hierarchy
so i need to put non empty value of the CODE field into empty CODE fields according to information in the field LINK

my table is like that

```
Objid link   code
1     0      555
2     1
3     2
4     3
```

ideally i need to do this inside one CREATE TABLE ... AS SELECT operator to create an mqt which would be later automatically refreshed on the regular base

all i have created by now is

```
CASE
        WHEN (code is NULL or code = '')
            THEN (select  code from  some_other_table
                  where objid = link and code is not NULL
              )
          WHEN (code != '' and code is not NULL)
            THEN code
          ELSE NULL
      END AS code,
```

i think it must be some kind of while loop which i can't put inside my CREATE TABLE AS SELECT

Are there any solutions without using procedures or functions?

Comment: Which release of DB2 are you using, and which OS is it running on? If you're lucky enough to be using IBM i, the solution may be simpler.

Comment: using db2 9, running on zOs

Answer (score 1):

I think what you might be looking for is a "select for update" type query.  This can be done similar to the following:

```
UPDATE SOME_DB.SOME_TABLE A
SET CODE = (SELECT SOME_CODE_FIELD
              FROM SOME_OTHER_DB.SOME_OTHER_TABLE B
             WHERE A.KEY = B.KEY)
WHERE CODE IS NOT NULL
   OR CODE = "";
```

This will update table A with the code value from table B, if it has one, for all rows on table A with a null code.  If table B has no code value, I believe the subselect will return null (provided the code column in table B is nullable) and the value of that code on table A will remain null.

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing a CREATE TABLE AS SELECT, can't you just join to the table that has the missing code?

```
SELECT
 COALESCE(CASE WHEN code='' THEN null ELSE code END,so.code) as code
FROM CodeTable ct
LEFT JOIN SomeOtherCodeTable so ON 
 ct.objid = so.link 
 AND so.code IS NOT NULL
```